# Can a non-PID noetherian integral domain have all PID localizations?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, principal-ideal-domains, localization, noetherian

If a noetherian integral domain R has all its localizations by maximal ideals being PIDs, does it imply that R itself is a PID?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Version:** No, an example would be the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$. I'll explain in the long version, why this example was chosen and why it does not satisfy your criteria.

**Motivation:** The idea is to first give a name to a Noetherian domain $A$ of Krull dimension one (if localization at every maximal is a PID, then the dimension is necessarily one), such that localization at every *prime* (not just maximal) ideal is a PID. This, as we will see, is a *Dedekind domain*. It is also known that if a Dedekind domain is a UFD, this it is a PID. So I have translated (a stronger version of) your question into:

> **Q:** Does there exists a Dedekind domain that is not a UFD? **A:** Yes!

**Long Version:**
If you consult Atiyah & MacDonald, chapter 9 (Valuation Rings), you will see the following statements:

> **Proposition 9.2:** Let $A$ be a Noetherian local  domain of [Krull] dimension one, $\mathfrak{m}$ its maximal ideal, $k=A/\mathfrak{m}$
> its residue field. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is a discrete valuation ring;
> 2. $A$ is integrally closed;
> 3. $\mathfrak{m}$ is a principal ideal;
> 4. $\dim \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m^2}=1$;
> 5. Every non-zero ideal is a power of $\mathfrak{m}$.
> 6. There exists $x\in A$ such that every non-zero ideal is of the form $(x^k)$, $k\geq 0$.

In particular, if a Noetherian local domain of dimension one $A$ is a PID then $A$ is a DVR (by $3\to 1$) and conversely, if $A$ is a DVR then $A$ is a PID (by $1\to 6$).

Now we define a Dedekind domain:

> **Proposition 9.3:** Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of [Krull] dimension one. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A$ is integrally closed;
> 2. Every primary ideal in $A$ is a prime power;
> 3. Every local ring $A_\mathfrak{p}$ ($\mathfrak{p}\neq 0$) is a DVR;
>
> A ring satisfying any (so all) of these conditions is called a *Dedekind domain*.

A very famous example of Dedekind domains are the following group (for a proof see [here, proposition 13.5](http://mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013-c13.pdf))

> Let $\mathbb{Q}\subset K$ be a finite field extension [This is called a *number field*], and let $R$ be the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$. Then $R$ is a Dedekind domain.

This is how the example in the short version is made. I'll leave it to you to show $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}i]$ is not a UFD.

Comment: Hamed, thanks a lot for such an extensive reply.