# If each subring of the fraction field of an integral domain $\mathcal{R}$ (and properly containing $\mathcal{R}$) is a PID, is $\mathcal{R}$ a PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples, principal-ideal-domains

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be an $\textrm{integral domain}$ such that for all $\mathcal{S}\underset{\text{containing $1$}}{\underset{\text{subring}}\subseteq\textrm{Frac}(\mathcal{R}})$

with $$ \mathcal{R}\subsetneq{\mathcal{S}}\subset \textrm{Frac}{(\mathcal{R})}$$ is a PID $(\textrm{principal ideal domain})$.

Conjecture: $\mathcal{R}$ is a PID.

---

We know the converse is true i.e for a PID $\mathcal{R}$ and any subring $S$ of $\textrm{Frac}(\mathcal{R}) $ containing $1$ and contained in $\mathcal{R}$ is a PID.

A particular case: Any subring $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $1$ is a PID as $\mathbb{Z}\subset S\subset \textrm{Frac}(\Bbb{Z}) =\Bbb{Q}$

Comment: Not sure off the top of my head. But some thoughts: If every prime of $R$ is principal, then $R$ is a PID. If not, try localizing so that a nonprincipal prime is the unique maximal ideal, see if the ideal remains nonprincipal in the localization.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin This is probably a silly question, but assuming one has an example like that, then did you have ideas about why the intermediate rings were PIDs?  Or did you just mean those examples would be good ones to check to see if they _happen_ to work out?

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2852580/29335

Comment: @rschwieb it's just what I would try, either to see if I get a contradiction, or to see what may be going on to try to construct a counterexample...

Comment: If I am not wrong, the valuation ring of dimension two $\mathbb Z_{(p)}+X\mathbb Q[[X]]$ is a counterexample. Its only proper overring is $\mathbb Q[[X]]$.

Comment: Your "converse" statement is also false. Take $K:=\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-6}]\subset \Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{-3},\sqrt{2}]=:L$, the first having class number $2$ and the second having $1$. This means the rings of integers $O_K\subset O_L$ is a counter-example, as $O_L$ is PID, while $O_K$ is not.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim The converse refers to overrings of R which are contained in the field of fractions of R.

Comment: @user26857 It is true that what you write is the correct converse, hence my quotation marks. But what I am refering to is what OP has actually written and named the "converse".

Answer (score 1):

The conjecture does **not** hold true. There are both Noetherian and non-Noetherian counter-examples.

**Note 1.** Let $R$ be an integral domain. From now on, we call a ring $S$ an *overring* of $R$, if $S$ contains $R$ and $S$ is in turn contained in the field of fractions of $R$.

**Note 2.** We shall take for granted the following facts.
Every [valuation domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) is Bézout. A valuation domain is therefore Noetherian if and only if it is a [discrete valuation domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring) (DVR).
An overring of a valuation domain is in turn a valuation domain.
If $R$ is a valuation domain of Krull dimension $0 < d < \infty$, then every proper overring of $R$ has dimension at most $d - 1$ [1, Theorem 10.1, (i) and (ii)].

As already noted by Wojowu in a comment (at the time the question was still on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/)), any non-discrete $1$-dimensional [valuation domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) $R$ satisfies OP's condition on overrings without being a PID. Indeed, we have:

> **Claim 1 [1, Exercise 10.5].** Let $R$ be an integral domain and let $K$ be its field of fractions. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> - The ring $R$ is a valuation domain of Krull dimension $1$.
> - The ring $R$ is a maximal proper subring of $K$.

If $R$ is a non-discrete $1$-dimensional [valuation domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_ring) then $R$ is not a [PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain) since it is not a [DVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring).
Furthermore, it trivially satisfies OP's condition on overrings because of the above claim.

**Example 1. [1, Exercise 10.11]**
Let $K$ be a field and let $X$ and $Y$ be indeterminates. Let $\alpha$ be an irrational positive real number. Let $\nu: K[X, Y] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ be the map defined by $\nu(\sum c_{m, n}X^m Y^n) = \min \{m + \alpha n \, \vert\, c_{m, n} \neq 0\}$. Then $\nu$ defines a valuation of $K(X, Y)$ with value group $\mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{Z}\alpha$. Let $R = \{ f \in K(X, Y) \, \vert \, \nu(f) \ge 0 \}$ be the valuation domain defined by $\nu$. Then $R$ has Krull dimension $1$ but its value group has rational rank $2$, hence $R$ isn't a DVR as DVRs have their value group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Example 2. (inspired by user Wojowu and this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521597))**
Let $K$ be a field and let $R = K[[\mathbb{Q_{\ge 0}}]]$ the ring of formal power-series of the form $\sum_{q \in \mathbb{Q}_{\ge 0}} a_q X^q \, (a_q \in K)$. Then $R$ is a $1$-dimensional valuation domain with value group $\mathbb{Q}$. In particular $R$  is not discrete. See also this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521574) for other examples of this kind.

If $R$ is a local domain satisfying OP's condition on overrings, then localizing $R$ at prime ideals shows that the Krull dimension of $R$ is at most $2$.

Until now, the given examples are all local (valuation domains are local Bézout domains) and non-Noetherian.
Here is an example that is a $1$-dimensional local and **Noetherian** domain, but which is not integrally closed.

**Example 3 (inspired by this [MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1521597)).**
Let $K$ be field and let $R = K[[X^2, X^3]]$ be the ring of formal power-series over $K$ of the form $a + X^2f$ with $a \in K, f \in K[[X]]$. It is not difficult to check that every proper overring of $R$ contains $X$ or $X^{-1}$. This shows that $K[[X]]$ is the only proper overring of $R$ properly contained in the fraction field $K((X))$ of $R$.

In a comment, @user26857 gives a remarkable example satisfying OP's condition on overrings. It is a valuation domain of Krull dimension $2$ (and value group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}^2$ endowed with lexicographical order). It is therefore not a PID, although it is a Bézout domain with a principal maximal ideal:

**Example 4 (@user26857).** Let $p$ be a rational prime and let $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \{\frac{r}{s} \, \vert \, r \in \mathbb{Z}, s \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus p\mathbb{Z} \}$. Then ring $R = \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} + X \mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ is a $2$-dimensional valuation domain with rank $2$ whose only proper overring strictly contained in the field of fractions $Q((X))$ of $R$ is $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$, that is, a DVR. The first part of the assertion follows from [1, Theorem 10.1.(iv) and the Remark before Theorem 11.2], i.e., the construction of the *composite* of $\mathbb{Q}[[X]]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$; the second part can be checked directly.

It follows from Claim 1 that every $2$-dimensional valuation domain with value group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (with lexicographical order) satisfies OP's condition on overrings.

> **Lemma 1.** If $R$ is non-local and satisfies OP's condition on overrings, then $R$ is a $1$-dimensional [Prüfer domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain).

> *Proof*. We claim that an overring of $R$ is integrally closed. It is obvious for proper overrings of $R$. The domain $R$ is the intersection of those overrings by [1, Theorem 4.4.7]. Localize at prime ideals to prove the assertion about the dimension.

If $R$ is a Noetherian Prüfer domain, that is a [Dedekind domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_ideal_domain), and if $R$ contains at least one non-zero prime element, then $R$ satisfies OP's condition on overrings if and only if $R$ is a PID. Indeed, the [ideal class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) of $S^{-1}R$ is identifies with the ideal class group of $R$ for every monoid $S$ generated by some non-zero prime elements of $R$.

Here is a Noetherian counter-example directly inspired by the [Zoe Allen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1107685/zoe-allen).

> **Claim 2.** There is a Dedekind domain $R$ satisfying OP's condition but which is not a PID.

> *Proof.* Let $D$ be a Dedekind domain with a non-trivial finite cyclic [ideal class group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_class_group) $C$, say $D = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ with $C \simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $D$ whose intersection with every maximal ideal of $D$ is empty and which is maximal with respect to this property. (Such a set $S$ exists by Zorn's lemma; the monoid generated the units and by the non-zero prime elements of $D$ satisfies the desired property, but isn't necessarily maximal). Then $R := S^{-1}D$ is a Dedekind domain with ideal class group $C \neq \{1\}$, hence it is not a PID. By construction, $T^{-1}R$ is a PID for every multiplicative subset $T$ of $R$ which contains at least one non-zero non-unit element. As every overring of $R$ that properly contains $R$ is of this form [2, Proposition 1; the result is shown to hold more generally for [Krull domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_ring)], the proof is complete.

---

**About the converse.**

It is an easy exercise to show that:

- every overring of a Bézout domain $R$ is a localization $S^{1}R$ of $R$ with respect to some multiplicative subset of $R$.
- the localization of a Bézout domain (resp. a PID) with respect to any multiplicative subset is again a Bézout domain (resp. a PID).

The following is now immediate:

> **Claim 3.** Let $R$ be a PID. Then every overring of $R$ is a PID.

---

**Towards a characterization.**

> **Claim 4.** Let $R$ be an integral domain which satisfies OP's condition on overrings. Then the Krull dimension of $R$ is at most $2$. If $R$ is local, then either
>
> - $R$ is integrally closed, in which case $R$ is a valuation domain, or
> - the integral closure of $R$ in its field of fraction is a PID, in which case $R$ is $1$-dimensional.

> If $R$ is not local, then $R$ is a Prüfer domain of Krull dimension $1$.
> If $R$ is Noetherian and not local, then $R$ is a Dedekind domain.

> *Proof.* If $R$ is not local, then the corresponding statement has already been proved with Lemma 1. In particular, the Krull dimension of $R$ is $1$ in this case. Assume now that $R$ is local. If $R$ is not integrally closed, then its integral closure within its field of fractions is a PID, by assumption. As PIDs are $1$-dimensional, the Krull dimension of $R$ is $1$ [1, Exercise 9.2, the dimension of an integral domain and its integral closure coincide].
> If $R$ is local and integrally closed, it is a Prüfer domain since all its proper overrings are integrally closed (see the [Integral closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain) section). The ring $R$ is therefore a valuation domain since it coincides with its localization $R_{\mathfrak{m}}$, with $\mathfrak{m}$ the maximal ideal of $R$. (The latter ring is a valuation domain, see (see the [Localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_domain) section)). Localizing at non-maximal prime ideals of $R$, if any, we immediately infer that the Krull dimension of $R$ is at most $2$.

> **Claim 5.** Every $1$-dimensional valuation domain satisfies OP's condition on overrings.
> A $2$-dimensional valuation domain satisfies OP's condition if and only if its value group is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times G$, endowed with the lexicographical order,
> for some non-trivial additive subgroup $G$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

> **Claim 6.** Let $R$ be a Noetherian $1$-dimensional domain which is not integrally closed.
> Let $\tilde{R}$ be the normalization of $R$, that is, the integral closure of $R$ with in its field of fractions.
> If $R$ satisfies OP's condition on overrings then $\tilde{R}$ is semiloca and the $R$-module $\tilde{R}/R$ is simple. In particular, the ring $R$ is a Bass domain (see [3, Theorem 2.1]).

To be continued.

---

[1] H. Matsumura, "Commutative Ring Theory", 1986.
[2] L. Claborn, "Every abelian group is a class group", 1966.
[3] L. Levy, R. Wiegand, "Dedekind-like behavior of rings with $2$-generated ideals", 1985.

Comment: I have only one question: if one wants to explain to an undergraduate student how that valuation ring look like, how could we do this? (I'm asking  since the question is at an undergraduate level.)

Comment: @user26857 I realise that I didn't answer your question: how to introduce Example 1 above to undergraduates? The example ring $R$ is a subring of $K(X, Y)$, so its elements are quotients of two irreducible polynomials in $K[X, Y]$. To decide if such a quotient belongs to $R$, we order monomials with the monomial order induced by $(m, n) \mapsto m + n \alpha$ and compare the smallest monomial of the numerator with the smallest monomial of the denominator.

Comment: ... Describing the polynomials which are the units of $R$ is instructive. It's reminiscent of the description of the units in $K[[X]]$ in regards of its obvious monomial order.

Answer (score -1):

This is incorrect. See the comments.

---

your question is whether every proper localisation of $R$ being a PID means $R$ is a PID.

The localisation of a localisation is a localisation, so we can consider the partial order of all localisations of $R$, with natural homomorphisms between them. The localisation of a PID is a PID, so we know that the subset of this order which are not PIDs is downwards-closed. Your question is then whether this partially ordered subset can have a maximal element (an element that cannot be properly localised into another non-PID, but which is not a PID itself).

Assuming the $R$ we start with is not a PID, this partial order of non-PIDs will be non-empty. And if we have a chain in this partial order, the direct limit that the homomorphisms give us will be another localisation of $R$. So if the localisations of $R$ in this chain being non-PIDs means their direct limit is not a PID, that would give an upper bound on every chain in the partial order of non-PID localisations. So by Zorn's lemma there would be maximal element in this partial order (and you get one for any non-PID integral domain $R$).

Comment: Note: it is not generally true that all overrings $\cal S$ of a domain $\cal R$ are localizations (if so this implies $\cal R$ is Prufer, e.g. see work of E. Davis, and Gilmer & Ohm on QR-domains).

Comment: @BillDubuque: Indeed for Dedekind domains, the property "all overrings are localizations" is equivalent to the divisor class group being torsion (see Prop 3.13 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306322.pdf))

Comment: @math54321 That's already in the *Math. Ann.* $153$ [$1964$ paper of Gilmer and Ohm](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0153?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B110%5D%2C%22pan%22%3A%7B%22x%22%3A0.496%2C%22y%22%3A0.834%7D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22zoom%22%3A1%7D) I mentioned implicitly above, see Corollary $2.6$: If $D$ is noetherian, then $D$ has the QR-property iff $D$ is a Dedekind domain such that every ideal of $D$ has a power which is principal.